# Vue application. How to skip authentication to show some component?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, routes, vue-router

I am working with vue and laravel application. I need to show component without user having to login. At the moment, to view the component(that has safety instructions), user have to login. But Now The component is needed outside meaning no login required to view that specific page. How can I achieve this in vue laravel application?

Answer (score 0):

If your Vue app is under protection of 'auth' middleware, you won't be able to reach it before login. Where you need Vue component use web middleware. But to be able to fetch data by Vue component, you will still need a token protection like Sanctum.

Comment: I have taken out the routes from auth middleware in the backend and it works but the problem is with Vue now. The front end is messed up. Is there any way in the vue front end side, where I can separate that particular routes from other protected routes.
The Dashboard items are all outside.

Comment: Create a different route.

Comment: It works without creating different route. I made a <p> tag with onClick function that display the component and after the work is done, I pushed the root component back into the router. Thank you.